# Nativescript(android): how to get getSupportFragmentManager() working?

Tags: android, nativescript

I want to add a selection of country codes in my app. Browsed few plugins, settled with this ( https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/country-picker-android ).
But when I am trying to implement it, I'm stopping here:

`picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");`

The android docs says that the function is located here:

`(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity as any).getSupportFragmentManager()`

but it returns 'getSupportFragmentManager is not a function'.

And `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` returns `null`.

How to make this work?

Comment: I can't recall all the specifics of the fragments and the activity being used with NativeScript, but here's a plugin I wrapped that used a fragment. It wasn't the `supportFragment` though and I think there was an issue at one time accessing that. https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-color-picker/blob/master/colorpicker.android.ts#L42

Comment: With that said ^^^, use the actual activity instance of the NS app. import the application module and use it to access the `startActivity` that will give you the activity. I still think there might be an issue using the supportFragment. It's possible that things have changed enough in recent months it might work though :)

Comment: Ok, changed code to `picker.show( application.android.startActivity.getFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");`, now Null error is no more, but a new error is in place: `Failed resolving method show on class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

Comment: I know this is crazy old, but @Starwave did you solve the `Failed resolving method show` error?

Comment: Unfortunately no, didn't end up crafting that module at all...